# How to evaluate model while the data splitted manually in deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, sequence, evaluate

I split my dataset separated with my model file.
So in my model file, I just run the model and set which is train, val, and test.
My model already has good results, but I struggled when I want to evaluate and predict the model.

Here's my code to set which is train, val, and test file.

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=45,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
fill_mode="nearest")
```

when I run this code

```
score = model.evaluate(train_generator, test_generator, verbose=1)
```

this error appeared

```
ValueError: `y` argument is not supported when using `keras.utils.Sequence` as input.
```

[image: ValueError: y argument is not supported when using keras.utils.Sequence as input.]

Here's my full code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11RXvin1sruAvzBahqEdAoaLXTBENtvVZ?usp=sharing

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you should be passing both your `train_generator` and `test_generator` when evaluating your model. Maybe try this:

```py
score = model.evaluate(test_generator, verbose=1)
```

Unlike the the method `model.fit` that can take a training and a validation set, `model.evaluate` only accepts one set of inputs.

Comment: Well, it's working now. i though that i've to give two parameters inside the model.evaluate() like what i see on the other source. Thanks for your help bro